# how to pad images of different sizes and making them of same size by putting the original image in the middle in matlab?

Tags: image, matlab

I have images of different sizes. I want to specify the width and the height. All the images should be padded with black pixels putting the actual image in the middle.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [padarray](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/padarray.html) to specify how many black pixels you want to add around the edge of the image.