# Resize images Matlab

Tags: matlab, resize-image

I want to resize images, but it should keep the height/width ratio when doing the resizing. What I do is, first I check whether which side (width or height) is the long. If the width is long, I'll give 150 to the width's size and resize the height without affecting to the shape of the image and vise versa. I am talking this resized image for a edge detection algorithm and output binary image is sent to the neural network which requires constant number of inputs. In this case, one side of (width or height) the image is 150 and other side is less than 150(vary from image to image). But I want to add black color to the other side(less than 150) until its size is 150. So, I can sent 150*150 inputs to the neural network.
Question is How can I add black color to the other side(less than 150) until its size is 150?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Charles Brunet Question is How can I add black color to the other side(less than 150) until its size is 150?

Comment: This sort of thing has been asked before: [how to pad images of different sizes and making them of same size by putting the original image in the middle in matlab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126945/how-to-pad-images-of-different-sizes-and-making-them-of-same-size-by-putting-the), [how to concatenate an image with a matrix horizontally in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780463/how-to-concatenate-an-image-with-a-matrix-horizontally-in-matlab)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imresize.html
http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/padarray.html

```
newim = imresize(im, 150 / max(size(im));
paddedim = padarray(newim, size(newim) - 150, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Creates an matrix of zeros. Calculate the position of the top-left pixel. Then copy your image to that matrix slicing from the top-left pixel.

Comment: If u don't mind, can you please mention the matlab functions to copy image to another slicing from top-left pixel?